# Convergence of an oscillating power series to a positive number

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series

$$ S =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i-1} c_{i} x^{2i} = c_1 x^{2} - c_2 x^{4} + c_3 x^{6} - \dots$$

The coefficients $c_i$ are all positive numbers, and they do not depend on $x$.

$x$ is also assumed to be positive.

Are there are any conditions which may be met by the $c_i$ which ensures the series converges to a positive number?

For example, if I can bound the coefficients from beneath and above, and write the series as a difference or sum of two geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

$$ S =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i-1} c_{i} x^{2i} = c_1 x^{2} - c_2 x^{4} + \dots.$$

Let $a_i=(-1)^{i-1}c_ix^{2i}$,

By root test,

Let $\alpha=\lim_{i\to\infty}\text{sup}\sqrt[i]{|a_i|}.$

$\alpha=\lim_{i\to\infty}\text{sup}\sqrt[i]{|c_ix^{2i}|}$

and so on...

Comment: Thank you. Does the root test provide information about convergence to a positive number. or just convergence?

Comment: @apkg Why not...series is convergent if $\alpha<1$ so this will give a range of $c_i$.

Comment: Can the series converge to a negative number?

Comment: @apkg Yes, it is possible...for instance $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-1\right)^{n} 2^{- n}=- \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: So, then, the root test here would only prove that my series converges, not that it converges to a positive number?

Comment: @apkg Yes, it just says whether the series converge or not.

Comment: Any way to decide if it converges to something positive?

Comment: @apkg Not specifically(in case of infinite series)...for this you have to check sum of series.

Comment: Ok, so on the whole there are no special conditions, I see. I would need the actual sum.

Comment: @apkg Ok...I think you are done! :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @apkg You're welcome!